# Formatting date in java.time

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

I am trying to format date were is given in following format `05051988`. I want to use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to format in next `05 may 1988`.

I have create private method that i will use later in same class to input formatted date in text. I have already made some code but i at the moment I'm getting `1988-05-05` if I use `MM`, if I replace it with `MMM` then it is giving me error message that can not be parsed.

```
private LocalDate parseDate(){
    LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy"));
    return dateOfBirth;
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05051988' could not be parsed at index 2
```

Comment: What message did you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05051988' could not be parsed at index 2

Comment: If you use MMM. The date input must be "05May1998". Not "05051988"

Comment: it is given as "05051988", i need to format it to "05 May 1988", but if i leave as MM then i am getting 1988-05-05 but when i change it to MMM then it is throwing me exception

Comment: Idk what `date` is in that context but something tells me it'd be better to pass it as a parameter or if you don't want to do that then maybe you should consider not having a `parseDate()` method at all. Nothing to do with the problem, just suggestion

Comment: date is part of String were i have like name, last name, date of birth and place of birth, i had to create new array and split it so it shows me separate information about persons, now for date was given to formatted in to different format.

Comment: I have no issue parsing a `String` of `05051988` using the code you provided.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The string format which your using (05 may 1988) is incorrect. When ever we are using MMM as a date format, we have to pass the month value as 'May' instead of 'may'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to use "ddMMyyyy" to parse the date.  Then use "dd MMM yyyy" to format it when you print it.

Something like this:

```
String reformat(String dateOfBirth) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateOfBirth, fomatter);
    return formatter2.print(date);
}
```

Comment: I have try like this DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy"); DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy"); LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateOfBirth, fomatter); but then i dont know how to proceed and put it in return xxx; any suggestion?

Comment: (a) Please add that code to your question.  (b) LocalDate does not carry to format around with it.  You'd have to be returning a string to do that.  if that's what you want, then use "return formatter2.print(date);"

Comment: Sorry. may I ask you why did you put print in return, when i try it is giving me error message "cannot find symbol, symbol: method print(LocaDate), location: variable fomratter2 of type DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought you were using the Joda library.  I didn't realize those classes are available in java 8 now.  For java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter you can probably use "return formatter2.format(date);"

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)